# Achieve this layout

Tags: html, css

could someone please advise me how I would go about achieving this layout.

[image]

I have tried to use tables and floated divs. The issue is I need B and C to have the same content height and I am trying to do this responsively, so fixed values cannot be used.
I have got so far as to have the layout, but without B and C having matching heights.
Preferably I would like to do this solely with css and html. 
I have searched for some basic templates but am unable to find anything that quite fist the bill.
Any help would be appreciated. I do have code if needed, but its of no real use. The picture says it all.

Comment: I'd consider changing the title of this post, as nobody who is having the same problem in the future will ever find this on Google!

Comment: [Because I'm bored](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/19856870/) (probably not very compatible with less up-to-date browsers).

Comment: @Ben any suggestions for the title is welcome. If I knew how to call this layout believe me I would be searching that term right now.

Comment: Downvotes without reasoning. cheers

Comment: You should really include your attempted code. It helps us to see your intent, and you wouldn't have mass downvotes and close votes.

Comment: @thirtydot I do state I will include code if necessary. Pretty sure people have chosen to skip this part. Anyway questions answered.

Comment: People should not have to request that you show you efforts so far. They are an expected part of most SO questions.

Comment: @Quentin point taken. 99% of the comments I have made request code

Comment: @thirtydot point taken. 99% of the comments I have made request code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox at least, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9vH8r/1/

HTML

```
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b"><p>B</p><p>B</p><p>B</p></div>
<div id="c"><p>C</p><p>C</p><p>C</p><p>C</p></div>
```

CSS

```
body, html{ padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100%; }
#a{
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 background: red;
 height: 100%;
}
#b, #c{ width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
 margin: -16px 0 0 200px;
}
#b{ background: green; }
#c{ background: blue; }
```

That should do it . . .

Comment: That will break as soon as the content is longer than the view port.

Comment: It probably will but it's a good starting point . . .

Answer (score -1):

This isn't easy to achieve in all browsers (as you've discovered), the only surefire way would be floating a then putting b and c in a container and floating that, with the widths as percentages and do the height with a bit of javascript.

However if you don't care about old browser (I know, the dream right!) you may have more luck using the CSS 3 flexbox.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Good luck!